# How to add a combobox values in Odoo?

Tags: combobox, odoo

I am new in odoo, how can I add a combo box with hard coded values (3 values) in opportunities form (when create new opportunities).

I successfully add a simple field from database structure and from user interface. but for combo box (many2one relation).

Answer (score 1):

This Is **OpenERP V7 And V8** Code You Use This Code in Your Model

```
'type': fields.selection([('lead', 'Lead'), ('opportunity', 'Opportunity'), ('both', 'Both')],string='Type', required=True,)
```

and call In You XML VIEW FILE

```
<field name="marital_state" />
```

If You use **ODOO Sass 6 or ODOO Master** Then Code Maigret

```
type = fields.Selection([('lead', 'Lead'), ('opportunity', 'Opportunity'), ('both', 'Both')],string='Type', required=True,)
```

and call In You XML VIEW FILE

```
<field name="marital_state" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Selection field:

```
marital_state = fields.Selection(selection=[('single', 'Single'),
                                                ('married', 'Married'),
                                                ('divorced', 'Divorced'),
                                                ('widower', 'Widower/widow')],
                                                string='Marital state')
```

Comment: That's python code. You must write it in the model that you want. And you should write the field in the xml view: <field name="marital_state" />